# Plot rows of a 2d matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, signals, matlab-figure

I have a 2d matrix `A` (`100 x 100`) where each row contains a signal to be plot.
I want to plot all of the signals in the same figure with different color for each row. How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually look [at the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_X) for `plot` you'll see that if you pass it a matrix, it will plot each column as a separate plot object on the same axes. As such you can simply pass the transpose of your data to `plot`.

```
% Example data
A = magic(10);

% Create a plot for each row
hplot = plot(A.');
```

This will plot each signal using the next plot color.

[image]

If you want to ensure that you have all different colors, you can use a colormap (such as `parula`) to explicitly set a different color per plot.

```
set(hplot, {'Color'}, num2cell(parula(size(A, 1)), 2))
```

[image]

**Update**

If you want to label your plots you could simply use `legend` to do this.

```
displaynames = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('Plot %d', x), 1:size(A, 1), 'uni', 0);
set(hplot, {'DisplayName'}, displaynames.');

legend(hplot)
```

[image]

Or if you have too many plots to reasonably fit within a legend you can create an interactive plot that highlights a given plot when you mouseover it. Here is an example of such a thing.

```
htitle = title('');

set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(s,e)motionCallback(hittest(s)))
motionCallback(hplot(1));

function motionCallback(plt)
    % Don't do anything if not a line object
    [tf, ind] = ismember(plt, hplot);

    if ~tf; return; end

    set(hplot, 'linewidth', 1)
    set(plt, 'LineWidth', 3)
    set(htitle, 'String', sprintf('SelectedPlot: %d', ind))
    drawnow
end
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i want to know for each line in plot , which row (transposed) it represents ?How is this possilbe?

Comment: @alphonse With 100 signals that's going to be tough to do with a `legend`. I will add something really quickly that would allow you to click on a plot to show where it came from.

Comment: Thanks again . Actually the number of signals is not 100 , its about 15. Thanks , i'll be pleased with anything you can

Comment: @alphonse Updated.